# Le gustan pinturas vs. le gustan las pinturas

Tags: significado

¿Hay diferencia de significado entre "le gustan pinturas vs. le gustan las pinturas"? Las dos frases las he inventado yo. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cual es tu idioma? Me parece que sería la misma cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Un mini-resumen que puede servir para empezar:

- Sustantivo

  - con artículo: "Le gustan las pinturas".
  - sin artículo: no encuentro ningún ejemplo que me suene bien y que no sea en realidad un adjetivo.
- Verbo

  - sin artículo: "Le gusta navegar".
  - con artículo (con fines poéticos): "Le gusta el navegar".
- Adjetivo

  - sin artículo: "Le gustan verdes" (en inglés sería "he likes them green")
  - con artículo (convierte el adjetivo en sustantivo): "Le gustan las verdes" (en inglés sería "he likes the green ones")

Answer (score 0):

No puedo pensar en una regla acerca de omitir el artículo que funcione para todos los casos. En general, la ‘norma culta’ considera incorrecta a dicha práctica cuando el objeto del verbo es un sustantivo. En cambio, es correcto cuando el objeto del verbo es un infinitivo.

> (*)Le gustan pinturas. 
> Le gustan las pinturas.

‘Típico caso en donde el no-ser termina siendo’—así es como llamaría a tu primer ejemplo. En efecto,  ver elipsis de este tipo no es algo tan raro pero por lo general requiere que el sustantivo:

- Esté en plural
- Esté ligado a un adjetivo. Esto significa añadir una determinación a la *ousía*; sin embargo, irónicamente, quitar el artículo da la sensación de que se está quitando otra determinación.

> —¿Te gustan las pinturas impresionistas? 
> —Sólo [me gustan] **las** [pinturas] de Monet. 
> [Hay un cierto subconjunto específico de pinturas impresionistas que me gustan]

> —Le gustan pinturas impresionistas. 
> [Lo que venga, con tal de que sea impresionista]

Hay muchas canciones—sobre todo de trap y reggaetón—en donde se observa este fenómeno:

> ‘Me gustan [las] exóticas a lo Sasha Grey’ [*Mula* de Eladio Carrión & Big Soto]

> ‘Me gustan [las] boricuas, me gustan [las] cubanas’ [*I Like It* de Cardi B, Bad Bunny & J Balvin]

> ‘Me gustan [las que son] como tú, las que no creen en sentimiento’ [*Soltera (Remix)* de
> Lunay, Daddy Yankee & Bad Bunny]

Comment: Me he perdido un poco en tu explicación. "Le gustan pinturas impresionistas" no me parece idiomático.

Comment: @RubioRic Más o menos, digo yo. De hecho aclaré que la norma culta lo considera incorrecto. Pero en la práctica lo veo bastante y sólo quería explicar qué diferencia veo con el no omitir el artíulo, la cual es meramente estilística; y el sentido ‘fundamental’ de lo que se dice no cambiará.  Obviamente, a menos que en el contexto se comprenda que hay un lugar llamado ‘Pinturas Impresionistas’, pero no tengo información de que eso sea cierto.